# rspec webmock to_raise error not raising error

Tags: ruby, rspec, webmock

I have the following code snippet and test

```rb
class Service
  def self.status(base_uri = 'localhost', basic_auth = {})
    base_uri = "#{ base_uri }/status"
    response = HTTParty.get(base_uri, basic_auth: basic_auth)
  rescue StandardError => e
    binding.pry
    raise "Error occured code: #{ response.code } msg: #{ e.message }"
  end
end
```

```rb
it 'should return error msg if url is not valid' do
  bad_url = "http://bar_url.com"
  expected = 'Error occured'
  stub_request(:get, bad_url).
            with(headers: {'Authorization'=>'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='}).
            to_raise(StandardError)

  expect { Service.status(bad_url, { username: @username, password: @password }) }.to raise_error(/#{ expected }/) 
end
```

This code is based on the [documentation](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock).
As a result rspec always raises an exception:

`expected /Error occured/, got #<WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError: Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request:  GET h...rization'=>'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='})`

Can anyone help me figure out what I should change to get a `StandardError` as a result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the service calls `"#{ base_uri }/status"` which is `http://bar_url.com/status` but the `stub_request` is declared with `http://bar_url.com` only, the Net::HTTP.Get looks for match with this instead of `http://bar_url/status`.
This is the reason why there is no error raising in the test.